# Как реализовать "вкладки" в qt (с++)?

Tags: c++, qt

Начал изучать qt, так что объясните "на пальцах", пожалуйста) Есть задача, без лишних "Окон" реализовать вкладки. То есть слева приложения есть, допустим, 4 кнопки - студенты, сотрудники, поиск и т.д. При нажатии на кнопку слева, с правой стороны окна меняется содержимое, с возможной реализацией поиска, выводом списка и т.д. Как наилучшим образом это реализовать? Я посидел, поразмышлял, но все решения выглядят как костыли. Если с помощью создания формы Qt или класса формы QT, то будет ли удобно в будущем между этими вкладками инфу передавать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: так есть же готовый виджет - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html или о его существования  Вы не знаете?

Comment: Или https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html если управление вкладками должно быть чуть более хитрым, чем просто включить нужную вкладку по тыку на кнопку